# switch in for loop when storing in arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a CSV file and I get each line of data and then store them in different arrays, this function works fine however it is more efficient with one function instead of having the switch statement and simple assignments, however, because I am assigning the arrays, I'm not sure how to do it,I also looked at [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653079/is-this-a-bad-pattern-switch-inside-for-foreach-loop) but in my case I cannot have functions as arrays because I'm assigning to different variables, I appreciate if anybody can give me a better substitution for my code.

```
 if (($handle = fopen($input, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",");
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                switch ($c):
                    case(0):
                        $urls404[] = $data[$c];
                        break;
                    case(3):
                        $detected[] = $data[$c];
                        break;
                    case(5):
                        $platform[] = $data[$c];
                        break;
                    case(7):
                        $redirects[] = $data[$c];
                        break;
                endswitch;
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could simplify your code like this:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $urls404[] = $data[0];
    $detected[] = $data[3];
    $platform[] = $data[5];
    $redirects[] = $data[7];
}
```